# php determine position of array key relative to another key

Tags: php, arrays, position

I was wondering if it was possible to determine what position a key in an array is in relation to another key.  I have a large multidimensional array and I need perform Function A when the key [E14_21] comes before [E14_20] and I need to perform a different Function B if not...

```
//perform Function A if:
[E14_20_0] => Array
    (
        [E14_21] => 3235
        [E14_20] => 96
    )
//Perform Function B if:
[E14_20_0] => Array
    (
        [E14_20] => 96
        [E14_21] => 3235
    )
```

Comment: I'm not sure that associative arrays are sequential, probably wrong though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
$keys = array_keys($E14_20_0);
if(array_search("E14_21", $keys) < array_search("E14_20", $keys)) {
  // function A
} else {
  // function B
}
```

You will of course need to add some sanity checks to make sure both keys exist in the array, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you might do this:

```
reset($E14_20_0);
first = each($E14_20_0);
second = each($E14_20_0);

if(first['key'] > second['key'])
{
    //do something
}
```

This is very specific to your example, but it might help you get started.

[reset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) will reset the array pointer to the "first" element.  [each()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) returns the key and value of the array based on the pointer and advances the pointer.  Then you can compare keys and perform your logic.